# Probability of getting a grade of C or better, given the student previously earned a C or better in the last 10 classes

Tags: probability

Assume events are dependent
Assume there are 13 possible grades for a given class (A+, A, A- ... D+, D, D-, F).
So for each class, 
Probability(Grade is C or better) = 8/13  -->  (P(A+) + P(A) + ... + P(C))

If a student has earned a C or better in his/her last 10 classes, what is the probability he/she earns a C- on the 11th class ?

I understand that if events are independent, then P(C-) = 1/13, but what if we assume the events are dependent?  How then do we solve it?

So, I was thinking ..
P(Grade is C or better 10 times in a row) = (8/13)^10 = 0.007789

Now, assuming A and B are dependent, Conditional Probability says ..
P(B given A) = P(A and B)/P(A)

So, 
P(B) = 1/13
P(A) = .007789
P(B and A) = P(A) + P(B) = .084717

then the conditional would be ...
.084717 / .007789 = 10.87 (which obviously makes no sense)

Can someone please help?

Comment: This is not clear at all.  You say the events are dependent, well...what is the nature of the dependence?

Comment: Roughly speaking, saying that two events are dependent means that when one of them happens, you know something (that you didn't know before) about the probability of the other happening.  But without details of exactly what you now know, the question can't be answered.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity.

Comment: @lulu It seems from your first comment like you figured out very clearly what the asker is confused about, so I'm not sure why you voted to close. (You can't expect everyone asking questions about math not to be confused; if they weren't confused, they wouldn't ask questions.)

Comment: @Misha Lavrov ... well said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake in your solution is saying that $P(A \text{ and } B) = P(A) + P(B)$.

This is not a rule that's always true; in fact, except when both events have probability $0$, it's *never* true.

So how do you find $P(A \text{ and } B)$? Well, if we assume that $A$ and $B$ are independent, it's $P(A) \cdot P(B)$. This brings us back to the original answer of $\frac1{13}$.

You want to consider the case when they're dependent... but that doesn't tell you anything specific, except that this is *not* necessarily true. You can find the answer if you say *how* they're dependent.